# Odoo 15 error after git hub code update and restart the odoo-service.service

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, odoo-15

Have face an error after update the odoo github code:

```
2023-12-31 14:17:02,355 229965 ERROR portal werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 85, in lookup
    r = d[key]
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/func.py", line 71, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 34, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj]
KeyError: ('ir.qweb', <function IrQWeb._compile at 0x7f6f8b3e0280>, 190, ('en_US', None, None, None, None, 1, None, None))


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 319, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 308, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 110, in application
    return ProxyFix(application_unproxied)(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/middleware/proxy_fix.py", line 187, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 87, in application_unproxied
    result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1305, in __call__

  File "/home/odoo/odoo/addons/http_routing/models/ir_http.py", line 502, in _dispatch
    return cls.reroute('/'.join(path) or '/')

    return self.translate(src_trans.get, value)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/translate.py", line 298, in xml_translate
    root = parse_xml(value)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/translate.py", line 276, in parse_xml
    return etree.fromstring(text)
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3237, in lxml.etree.fromstring
    
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1895, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
    
ValueError: can only parse strings - - -
2023-12-31 14:17:57,554 229968 INFO portal odoo.addons.base.models.ir_cron: Starting job `{'en_US': 'payment: post-process transactions'}`. 
2023-12-31 14:17:57,561 229968 INFO portal odoo.addons.base.models.ir_cron: Job `{'en_US': 'payment: post-process transactions'}` done.
```

After updating the code of Odoo 15 from off repo and restarting the service I got this error while trying to select my database.

Also, I have reverted to the previous commit but no use. If I create a new DB - it works fine.

Has somebody faced a such problem? It is possible to solve it or not?

Comment: where is the code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps:

1. Open the odoo.conf file.
2. Add the module auto-upgrade command using the -d your_db_name_here -u
   your_module_name_here along with existing parameters.
3. Save the changes to the odoo.conf file.
4. Restart the Odoo server and the instance.

This command triggers an upgrade for the specified module in the specified database. Once the issue is resolved and the module is updated successfully, you can remove the auto-upgrade command from the odoo.conf file.